# How does Android youtube hide the system ui, even when the dialog pops up

Tags: android, youtube, dialog, statusbar, navigationbar

I am currently using SystemUiHider for hiding the system status bar and navigation bar.

I came across with a issue that if I want to show a DialogFragment (which actually pops up a dialog), it does break the system ui hiding and show the status bar and navigation bar.

It looks like this [image]

You can see the screen got squashed after the dialog pop up

I thought what I want is the same effect as Youtube Android App

It looks like this [image]

After clicking on the option button on the screen top right, it pops up a dialog looking like this [image]

Which shows the status bar and navigation bar, but it is fine as it doesn't squash the actually video

So can anyone help me out of this? Thanks for any suggestion

I'm currently using SystemUiHider

```
mUIHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, mContentFrame,
    SystemUiHider.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | SystemUiHider.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES
    | SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
mUIHider.setup();
mUIHider.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

according to android using [Immersive view](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) will do. Like in the case below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    }

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm using systemuiHider for the previous fragment. It's set up with the IMMERSIVE_STICKY

Comment: If you find it relevant or helpful please tick it so as more can see